# Does F# have an equivalent to Haskell's take?

Tags: list, haskell, f#

In Haskell, there is a function "take n list" which returns the first n elements from a list. For example "sum (take 3 xs)" sums up the first three elements in the list xs. Does F# have an equivalent? I expected it to be one of the List-functions, but I can't spot anything that seems to match.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, it's called [`Seq.take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340299(v=VS.100).aspx). Usage seems to be identical to Haskell's: `Seq.take` *count source*. <strike>To use it on a list, use [`List.toSeq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340303(v=VS.100).aspx) first.</strike> (Update: Apparently from the comments, this isn't necessary.)

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Testing now. :)

Comment: Actually, haskell's take acts like Seq.truncate, not Seq.take.

Comment: Since list inherits from IEnumerable, you don't have to convert it to a sequence first from what I can see. Using Seq.take on a list worked fine.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yeah, you're right. I didn't know that. The documentation I linked explains the difference, which is pretty subtle in my opinion.

Comment: @McMuttons: Fair enough. I did expect Seq operations to work on a list, but I have almost no experience with F#, so wasn't sure. I mentioned the conversion function just in case.

Comment: Yeah, good function to know about either way. Appreciate the help. And damnit, I accidentally removed my +1 on your answer, but it doesn't seem to let me add it again unless you edit it in some way.

Answer (score 50):

To clarify a few things, the difference between `Seq.take` and `Seq.truncate` (as pointed out by @sepp2k) is that the second one will give you a sequence that returns *at most* the number of elements you specified (but if the length of the sequence is less, it will give you less elements).

The sequence generated `Seq.take` function will throw an exception if you try to access an element beyond the length of the original list (Note that the `Seq.take` function doesn't throw the exception immediately, because the result is lazily generated sequence).

Also, you don't need to convert the list to a sequence explicitly. Under the cover, `list<'a>` is a .NET class that inherits from the `seq<'a>` type, which is an interface. The type `seq<'a>`is actually just a type alias for `IEnumerable<'a>`, so it is implemented by all other collections (including arrays, mutable lists, etc.). The following code will work fine:

```
let list = [ 1 .. 10 ]
let res = list |> Seq.take 5
```

However, if you want to get a result of type `list<int>` you'll need to convert sequence back to a list (because a list is more specific type than a sequence):

```
let resList = res |> List.ofSeq
```

I'm not sure why F# libraries don't provide `List.take` or `List.truncate`. I guess the goal was to avoid reimplementing the whole set of functions for all types of collections, so those where the implementation for sequences is good enough when working with a more specific collection type are available only in the `Seq` module (but that's only my guess...)

Comment: @McMuttons: Thanks! I wasn't sure whether I should post it or not, because most of the things were already mentioned in the comments.. So, I'm glad it is usedul!

Comment: It looks like [`List.truncate`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#truncate) and [`List.take`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#take) are now in the core F# libraries

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Seq.take works, as others already have stated, but all Seq operations on a list come at a cost. In the case of Seq.take, it's not surprising, as the list has to be copied.</strike>

It's more noteworthy that, for example, Seq.concat on a list takes a lot more time than List.concat. <strike>I suppose that implies that you don't just access the list as a seq when you call a Seq.xxx function, but that the list in copied/converted to a Seq behind the scenes as well.</strike>

edit: The reason I drew the conclusion above, was this bench using F# interactive:

```
#time "on";;
let lists = [for i in 0..5000000 -> [i..i+1]];;
Seq.length (Seq.concat lists);;
List.length (List.concat lists);;
```

On my machine, the `List.length` version takes about **1.9 secs**, whereas the `Seq.length` version takes about **3.8 secs** (shortest time of a few repeated tests of the length lines only, excluding the list generation line).

Comment: I don't think that this is correct.  `list<'t>` implements the `seq<'t>` interface so there is no conversion necessary, nor is there any reason to expect a copy to be made.  Also, `Seq.take` works lazily, whereas `List.take` couldn't, so on a long list, the sequence operations will almost certainly be quicker if only the front of the resulting sequence is needed.  However, it may be true that implementing a `List.take` function via pattern matching would perform better than the `Seq.take` implementation which enumerates the list if you want to eagerly access all elements of the resulting list.

Comment: My conclusion about conversions taking place was probably wrong, but something's going on and it takes extra time. I edited my post and added some timings.

Answer (score -1):

Elaborating on [@Jonathan Tyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5951133/jonathan-tyson) comment

List.take is now part of the standard F# library and it is recommended to use that instead of the Seq.Take

The following should work

```
List.take <count>
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601293/how-can-i-return-a-specific-number-of-values-from-a-sequence-in-a-recursive-rand?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer to understand the difference between take and truncate