# How can I return a specific number of values from a sequence in a recursive random walk function?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to plot the first 100 values of this random walk function using F#/Xamarin. Whenever I call the function, my application freezes. I tried to get the count on this.RW, but that also freezes the application. Help appreciated!

```
module SimulatingAndAnalyzingAssetPrices = 
    type RandomWalk(price : float) = 
        let sample = Normal(0.0, 1.0).Sample()

        // Generate random walk from 'value' recursively
        let rec randomWalk price = 
            seq { 
                yield price
                yield! randomWalk (price + sample)
            }

        let rw = randomWalk 10.0

        member this.RW = rw
```

Note: This is from tryfsharp.org's finance section. My intent is to port it to iOS using Xamarin.

Edit:
Tried using the following code, but still getting an infinite sequence:

```
    let rw = randomWalk 10.0

    let rwTake = Seq.take 100 rw

    member this.RwTake = rwTake
```

Edit 2: Also tried

```
    let rw = randomWalk 10.0 |> Seq.take 100

    member this.RwTake = rw
```

Comment: When you say "still getting an infinite sequence", have you updated the graphing code to try to graph `this.RwTake` instead of graphing `this.RW`? Because "Oops, I forgot to update the other half of my code" is an easy mistake to make...

Comment: You are a smart man. That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `randomWalk` function produces an infinite sequence, so you should never call it without using [`Seq.take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340299.aspx) to limit the number of items to, say, the 100 you're trying to graph. If you call it directly, the app freezes because you'll never find the end of the infinite sequence. But if you graph `somePrice |> this.RW |> Seq.take 100`, you should no longer have your application freezing up any more.

And getting the count of an infinite sequence is also going to freeze up, because it will be going through the sequence trying to reach the end so it can return a count, but there's no end! You can never take a count of an infinite sequence.

**Update:** There's also [`Seq.truncate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370325.aspx). The difference between `Seq.take` and `Seq.truncate` lies in what happens if there are fewer items than expected. (This won't be the case for your `randomWalk` function, so you can use either `take` or `truncate` and you'll be fine, but in other situations you might need to know the difference.) If a sequence has only 5 items but you try to `Seq.take 10` from it, it will throw an exception. `Seq.truncate`, on the other hand, will return just 5 items.

So `Seq.take 10` will either return exactly 10 items, no more nor less, or else throw an exception. `Seq.truncate 10` will return *up to* 10 items, but might return fewer, and will never throw an exception.

For more details, see [Does F# have an equivalent to Haskell's take?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2632833/2314532)

Comment: Also, this random walk isn't going to be very random because `let sample = Normal(0.0, 1.0).Sample()` is bound once.  It would be better to use `let sample() = Normal(0.0, 1.0).Sample()` such that the value of the random walk was generated at each step of the recursion.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the quick answers! Tried your suggestion rmunn, and getting an unexpected behaviour. Have updated question to reflect that.